# output high resolution filled.contour figure in R

Tags: r, plot, png

I am trying to save my filled.contour plots as a high resolution(>600dpi) piture(png, jpeg....) in Rstudio. 
However, when I use the "export" function in the interface of Rstudio, the resolution is very low(the figure is only around 20kb).

Then I tried to use "PNG" command to save my plots, but I failed.

May I ask is there anyone knows how to achieve this?

Really appreciate for your kind help!

Comment: Please provide the command you used to save your plots.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this to maintain resolution when the image is rendered at a very large scale. To achieve that using the `png(...)` function, you have to set the size (`height` and `width` parameters) and also the resolution in ppi (`res` parameter). So the code below creates a png file of an 11 X 8.5 inch image at 600 ppi, or 6600 X 5100 pixels.  The file is 435KB.

```
# open the  png graphics device
png("volcano.png",res=600,height=8.5,width=11,units="in")

## the following is taken verbatim from the filled.contour(...) documentation
x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color=terrain.colors,
               plot.title = title(main = "The Topography of Maunga Whau",
                                  xlab = "Meters North", ylab = "Meters West"),
               plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(100, 800, by = 100))
                             axis(2, seq(100, 600, by = 100)) },
               key.title = title(main = "Height\n(meters)"),
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(90, 190, by = 10)))  # maybe also asp = 1
mtext(paste("filled.contour(.) from", R.version.string),
      side = 1, line = 4, adj = 1, cex = .66)
##

# close the graphic device
dev.off()
```

If you expect to render this at a physical size greater than 11 X 8.5, you would need to generate the png at the appropriate size.

Comment: Thanks ilhoward, but I have a problem in the first step opening the png graphics device. There is an error message in R studio says unable to start png() device. Do you have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to say as I can't reproduce the problem. Does the code above run as is (copy/paste/run) on your system?